# How connect Socket IO as client C#?

Tags: c#, plugins, socket.io, client, milestone

When I connect with **Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client.IO.Socket** client, it connects and immediately disconnects the client. Every second it repeats this. 
What is the reason? How can I keep alive connection?

```
    var socket = IO.Socket("http://127.0.0.1:3000");

    socket.On(Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client.Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, (fn) =>
    {
        socket.Emit("partInfo");

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

[You can use this free plugin and try to connect its easy solution for you this solution for Unity3D & C# only](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/socket-io-for-unity-21721)

Comment: It seems only for Unity4. Can you provide a link of example C#?